# DNS Server to detect HTTP status code

Tags: proxy, dns, server

There is any method to detect HTTP status code through a DNS server?

For example for the host www.stackoverflow.com my DNS returns 151.101.193.69 but how to read a 404 from www.stackoverflow.com/nopage.html to return something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed **Simple DNS plus** that checks for **NXDomain** and make a redirect to a custom server.

Answer (score 0):

No. DNS is a database where you can look up IP addresses from names. *Everything* to do with HTTP happens after you have an IP address to contact, which is to say long after DNS's job is already over.

Comment: That's what I knew, but what if I use some pharming just to parse an http status?